# Finding acceleration at a certain velocity

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

A race car starts from rest and travels east along a straight and level track. For the first $5.0s$ of the car's motion, the eastward component of the car's velocity is given by

$x\left(t\right)=\left(.960\frac{m}{s^3}\right)t^2$

What is the acceleration of the car when $v_x=15.5\frac{m}{s}$?

I tried to determine this by first assuming I need to find the velocity at $15.5\frac{m}{s}$, so I set the function above equal to that and solved it.  I got a time and figured I needed to plug that into the second derivative of the function, but at $x''$ there is no $t$ to account for.

Any tips on what I did wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remember that $x(t)$ is velocity not position.

Comment: You differentiated one too many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your velocity function equal to $15.5 \text{ m/s}$, and solve for $t$ to obtain the time time at which it will achieve this velocity.

Now, differentiate this function to obtain the acceleration $a(t)$ and find the acceleration at that time.

Comment: There is no $t$ when I differentiate $v(t)$ so that I can plug in $a(t)$...

Comment: @inquisitor That means the acceleration remains constant throughout the car's motion.

Comment: That's what I figured, but entering $1.92\frac{m}{s^3}$ is incorrect :(

Comment: @inquisitor Oh, I just realised that your $x(t)$ is supposed to represent the velocity of your car and not its position. I'll correct my answer (but I'd recommend you to use $v(t)$ for velocity and not $x(t)$).

Comment: This doesn't work either, would you mind showing me what you get?

Comment: @inquisitor I get about $7.71 \text{ m/s$^2$}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm at a loss for what I did wrong.  Your answer was correct.  My velocity function was set up like this $x\left(t\right)=\left(.960\frac{m}{s^2}\right)t^2=15.5\frac{m}{s}$  Solving this I got $8.072s^2$??

Comment: @inquisitor $15.5$ divided by $0.96$ is about $16.146$ (which is expected since $0.96$ is a little less than $1$). The square root of this should be a little greater than $4$ (it's approx. $4.018$).

Comment: Thanks, I must have punched something into my calculator incorrectly